# French list of word where I can use filters like nouns, singular form, verbs…

Tags: data-request, language, french

I often need to find a list of french words (sometimes english as well, but that's certainly for another question) where I can filter words depending on multiple criterias. For instance, I may like to select only nouns, singular nouns, or non-conjugated verbs (infinitif), nouns masculin... It would be even nicer if I could also filter depending on the frequency of the word.

Note that I'm fine if the file is simply a csv/sql/whatever format that I need to parse using python or alike.

One application could be to create a list of words to generate passphrase, in such a way that this list only contains nouns or verbs that are not conjugated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [Lexique.org](http://www.lexique.org/) or [OpenLexicon](https://github.com/chrplr/openlexicon).

Lexique gives the word, a phonological representation, morphological information, frequency in a subtitles corpus, etc.

OpenLexicon gathers multiple lexical databases, among which [many for French](https://github.com/chrplr/openlexicon/blob/master/datasets-info/README.md).

Answer (score 1):

I just found [this great database](https://kaikki.org/dictionary/French/index.html) extracted from the wikitionary

For instance one entry can look like:

```
  "pos": "noun",
  "head_templates": [
    {
      "name": "fr-noun",
      "args": {
        "1": "m"
      },
      "expansion": "volatile m (plural volatiles)"
    }
  ],
  "forms": [
    {
      "form": "volatiles",
      "tags": [
        "plural"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "word": "volatile",
  "lang": "French",
  "lang_code": "fr",
  "sounds": [
    {
      "ipa": "/vɔ.la.til/"
    },
    {
      "audio": "LL-Q150 (fra)-DSwissK-volatile.wav",
      "text": "Audio",
      "ogg_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/7/7d/LL-Q150_%28fra%29-DSwissK-volatile.wav/LL-Q150_%28fra%29-DSwissK-volatile.wav.ogg",
      "mp3_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/7/7d/LL-Q150_%28fra%29-DSwissK-volatile.wav/LL-Q150_%28fra%29-DSwissK-volatile.wav.mp3"
    }
  ],
  "categories": [],
  "senses": [
    {
      "raw_glosses": [
        "fowl, bird"
      ],
      "tags": [
        "masculine"
      ],
      "glosses": [
        "fowl, bird"
      ],
      "id": "volatile-fr-noun-FPyjimxu"
    }
  ]
}
```

Sadly the frequency is not present.

There is also this compressed version (many information is lost, but it's csv and potentially easier to parse) https://github.com/hbenbel/French-Dictionary/.